# Change Text when Links are Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on a collapsing div container using bootstrap. Its working perfectly until I tried to add a modification.

I added a text link that says "View More" so my users will know that there is more to text read. Anyway, I have written a jquery code to change the text "View More" to "Close" **WHENEVER** the DIV container is collapsed or shown.

**My Goal:**

When user decided to collapse the div container, I want it to change the "view more" text to "close"

**Here's my Problem:**

My JQUERY code only that modifies the text "VIEW MORE" to "CLOSE" only works at the first text links. The succeeding text links are not modified even if i clicked it.

Also, there are **five** "view more" text links in the page with same classnames (not sure if this info is relevant but its worth mentioning, i guess...)

Anyway, You can see what's wrong in the references i have provided below ([gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJdd.jpg) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/bendaggers/pen/dyoqqVE))

**Here's a GIF for your reference.**
[imgur.com/V8Q4RSj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJdd.jpg)

**Here's my complete code:**
https://codepen.io/bendaggers/pen/dyoqqVE

**Here's my JQUERY Code:**

```
$("#yt").click(function(){

  $('#closeopen').text($('#closeopen').text() == 'View More' ? 'Close' : 'View More');

});
```

I would appreciate anyone who could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS Pseudo-element [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

```
.collapse:not(.show) + .closeopen::before {
  content: 'View More';
}
.collapse.show + .closeopen::before {
  content: 'Close';
}
```

**Working Demo**

https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/gOpddZw

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA I died!

Comment: Thank you very much @User863! I didn't know that It can be done like this.

Comment: This solution is problematic when you have to use internationalization. It's hard to have different translation strings when more languages need it. Otherwise, if you only work with one language, then it's perfect !! :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos no issues [:lang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) pseudo-class is there

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(
  function () {
    jQuery('.toggleMe')
      .on(
        'click',
        function() {
          var state = jQuery(this).data('state');

          jQuery(this).data('state', 'closed' === state ? 'revealed' : 'closed');
          jQuery(this).text('closed' === state ? 'Close' : 'Read More');
        }
      );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span
  class="toggleMe"
  data-state="closed"
>
  Read More
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span
  class="toggleMe"
  data-state="closed"
>
  Read More
</span>
```

Comment: @BenDaggers keep in mind I have applied some changes, as the initial solution has the span text property in wrong order.

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Check my updated codepen link (https://codepen.io/bendaggers/pen/dyoqqVE), it only worked at the first view more link but the rest is the same.

Comment: @BenDaggers that's normal as you use ID as a selector. instead, you should change your selectors.

Comment: @BenDaggers and of course, if my solution solves your problem don't forget the tick the little checkmark bellow the two arrows at the left of my reply :)